# Set Spring Unit Test Profile From -D Variables

Tags: java, spring

I have got a test like this

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, DevConfig.class, ProdConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"prod", "dev"})
public class MyTest {
 ........
}
```

The AppConfig is the main config for my app

there are two config class created just fro my unit tests
the DEV config class loads test_dev.properties from my src/test/resource/...

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:test_dev.properties")
public class DevConfig {

}
```

the ProdConfig class loads prod.properties

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@PropertySource("classpath:test_prod.properties")
public class ProdConfig {

}
```

I want switch easily between prod and dev by changing the value in the @ActiveProfiles

But I want be able to switch test environment like

```
 mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev or prod  install
```

I have tried

```
   @ActiveProfiles({"prod", "dev"})
   then 
   mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev or prod  install
```

it seems the prod always gets picked up

I have seen solution like

```
@Test
    public void transferTenDollars() throws InsufficientFundsException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
        ctx.register(TransferServiceConfig.class, StandaloneDataConfig.class, JndiDataConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        // proceed with assertions as above ...
    }
```

but this is would lost the whole point of using the @ContextConfiguration annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the switch is

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

or even as an environment variable

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev mvn install
```

Comment: you are right. But removing @ActiveProfiles({"prod"})
was the key to solve my problem

Comment: reason remove  @ActiveProfiles({"prod", "dev"}) solved the problem is because instead of specifing the active profile from your code, you want to pass it from command line env var. thus no need to do a @ActiveProfiles

Comment: You can do both have the annotation with fixed profiles @ActiveProfiles({"foo"}) and add more from command line -Dspring.profiles.include=bar,baz